# Seaborn, change y-axis into the range of 0 to 100

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data set that I need to visualize with seaborn. I need to standardize the y axis value to have a range between 0 to 100. Since my max value is 70 on the y axis 70 is shown as its max value. Is it possible to keep the graph in the range of 100? How do you do it?

[image]

Comment: Just do `plt.ylim((0, 100))`